# JQuery onChange for Dynamic Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have reviewed several posts for similar issues but still haven't found a fix. I have a table with a single row(onLoad). At the click of a button, I am dynamically adding a table row(TR) to the table. Then there is a separate script to assign an ID to the table row. I have an onchange script that should give me the ID of one of the elements when it changes. It works for the first static row. It does not work for any dynamically added rows.

```js
$j(".main-wrapper tr:last").after("<tr class='well'><td><div style='display:inline' class='input-group'><select style='display:inline;width:100%'><option value='--None--'>--None--</option><option value='one'>One</option></select></div></td><td><div style='display:inline' class='input-group'><select class='discount-percentage' style='display:inline;width:100%'><option value='--None--'>--None--</option><option value='one'>One</option></select></div></td><td><div class='input-group'><span><input style='display:inline;width:100%' type='text' class='form-control' /></span></div></td><td><div class='input-group'><span><input style='display:inline;width:100%' type='text' class='form-control' /></span></div></td><td><div class='input-group'><input style='display:inline;width:100%' type='text' class='form-control' /></div></td></tr>");

$j(".line-item-table").on("change", 'main-wrapper tr select:first', function() {
  var dropVal = $j(this).val();
  var dropId = $j(this).parent().attr("id");
  alert("ID : " + dropId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any insight? Am I just overlooking something here?

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: Looks like just a typo to me.  You're missing the `.` before main-wrapper on the selector in your second line.  `$j(".line-item-table").on("change", '.main-wrapper tr select:first', function() {`

Comment: Adjusted that small typo but still getting the same results. Here is the fiddle... → https://jsfiddle.net/turminator/k6pdoLb7/

Comment: I have resolved this problem. Apparently I misread the other help articles. After dissecting every word of the previous posts regarding this problem, I realized my "static ancestor" wasn't so static and the identification of the dynamically created element was incorrect. It is working as desired now. Thanks for the input!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$j(".main-wrapper").on("change", 'tr select', function() {
  var dropVal = $j(this).val();
  var dropId = $j(this).parent().attr("id");
  alert("ID : " + dropId);
});
```

This works for me!